# Error in Matlab function deleteModelGenes

Tags: function, matlab

I am using function deletemodelGenes for deleting genes in a Human-Gem Model but having error on a line

```
    % Figure out if any of the reaction states is changed
  %  for j = 1:length(rxnInd)
 %       if (isfield(model, 'rules') && ~isempty(model.rules{rxnInd(j)})) %To avoid errors if the rule is empty
%            if (~eval(model.rules{rxnInd(j)}))
```

%                 constrainRxn(j) = true;
%              end
%           end
%        end

i commented this lines and now the function working properly i want to know if i run function without this lines is it ok or what changes need to be done to work this function properly?

Need to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this snippet is iterating through a struct of 'rules', which appear to be strings representing functions which are evaluated with `eval`.

Firstly, using eval is a bad practice. I'd suggest this models.rules{} is modified to use a cell array of function handles instead.

To answer your question, it looks like this code is checking a bunch of 'reaction states' by evaluating the eval statements contained in the cell array in turn and setting a `constrainRxn` flag if any return a false boolean.

This might do something in another part of the code, like exit early or raise an error.
Without context it's hard to say, but it's rare that code that is used in a calculation isn't necessary.

Comment: If you edit your question to post the specific error you've got, then perhaps that is something that could be resolved. However, my guess is that it involves other sections of the code as well, since it's performing an 'eval'. It could be a few different problems, which is part of the reason that eval is a bad idea to use.